# Adding a JLabel above a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, containers, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm having a hard time with containing a GridLayout so that adding a JLabel above it won't throw off anything. I've tried a few different things but still cant seem to get it aligned right.

It's a Tic Tac Toe game:

```
package assg01;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {
   private static final String TITLE = "Tic Tac Toe";
   private static final int WIDTH = 700;
   private static final int HEIGHT = 808;
   private Container content;
   private JLabel result;
   private JButton[] cells;
   private JButton exitButton;
   private JButton initButton;
   private CellButtonHandler[] cellHandlers;
   private ExitButtonHandler exitHandler;
   private InitButtonHandler initHandler;
   private boolean noughts;
   private boolean gameOver;
   private Container panel;
   private ImageIcon x,empty,o;

   public TicTacToe() {
    // Necessary initialization code
       setTitle(TITLE);
       setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       // Get content pane
       panel = getContentPane();
       //content.setBackground(Color.blue.darker())
       // Set layout
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
       // Create cells and handlers
       cells = new JButton[9];
       cellHandlers = new CellButtonHandler[9];
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           cells[i] = new JButton();
           cellHandlers[i] = new CellButtonHandler();
           cells[i].addActionListener(cellHandlers[i]);
       }
       // Create result label
       //result.setForeground(Color.white);
       // Add elements to the grid content pane
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           panel.add((cells[i]));
       }      
       init();
   }
   public void init() {
       // Initialize

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel ("Label") ;
        topPanel.add(myLabel);

       x=new ImageIcon("images/x.png");
       empty=new ImageIcon("images/empty.png");
       o=new ImageIcon("images/o.png"); 
       noughts = true;
       gameOver = false;
       // Initialize text in buttons
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           char ch = (char) (i + 1);
           cells[i].setIcon(empty);
           cells[i].setName(""+ch);
       }
       // Initialize result label
       setVisible(true);
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time with containing a `GridLayout` so that adding a `JLabel` above it won't throw off anything.

The trick here is to combine layouts:

- Create a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`
- Add the `GridLayout` to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`.
- Add the `JLabel` to the `PAGE_START` of the `BorderLayout`.

Another option is to use a `TitledBorder` (instead of the `JLabel`) for the `GridLayout`.

Comment: 1+,  the default layout of the content pane of  a JFrame is a BorderLayout. So there is no need to create the extra panel with a BorderLayout.

Comment: @camickr True. I just have the habit of calling `setContentPane(myUI)` ever since Sun decided to change the default layout of `JFrame` from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout`..  ;)